# Fragments overlapping on FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I am trying to add multiple fragments to a `FrameLayout`. I need to add them one below another. But they are overlapping.

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

            // Create instance of fragments
            FragmentPrimaryList firstFrag = new FragmentPrimaryList();
            FragmentSecondaryList secFrag = new FragmentSecondaryList();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // add fragment to the fragment container layout
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,firstFrag);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,secFrag);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

They looks like this. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: You are adding the new fragment but not hiding the old one.

Comment: That's what `FrameLayout` does. If you want them stacked top to bottom, use a vertical `LinearLayout` instead.

Comment: @MihirTrivedi I need to display both fragments at same time, one below another.

Comment: @MikeM. changed existing `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout`. But now display only one fragment. first fragment only.

Comment: The `Fragment`s' layouts need to `wrap_content` for their root `View`s' `layout_height`s.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes. `wrap_content` did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) method instead of the [add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) method.

The replace method hides the current fragment before adding new one, the add method simply adds the new fragment without disposing off the older fragment.

In order to retain the back stack, use the fragment transaction with [backstack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) management.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to display both fragments at same time, one below another

You can try the following layout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now add fragmments using:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container1,firstFrag);
```

make sure you Fragment's `layout_height = "wrap_content"`

Comment: Can't pre defined the FrameLayout s' as in your answer. It depend on the data receiving with a web service. It may need to show 3 or 4 fragments at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

**First fragment**

```
FragmentPrimaryList firstFrag = new FragmentPrimaryList();
FragmentManager  fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

// add fragment to the fragment container layout
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,firstFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**second fragment**

```
FragmentSecondaryList secFrag = new FragmentSecondaryList();
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,secFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add background to your fragments and make "android:clickable="true" to parent layout.